# Use params in react Link and get the value of it in another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, react-router-dom

The question may sound confusing but here's what i mean,
I have two components that are in no way related, they're not parent or child to each other basically,
This is the first Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const slug="NewYork"
        return (
            <Link to={`/TestRoute/${slug}`}>
                City
            </Link>
        );
    };
}
export default Test;
```

And here is my second Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Api extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const options = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('api_key'),
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        axios.get('urlLink/Slug' , options)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
            hi
        </div>
    }
}
```

And the Route` i'm using for the second Component is this

```
<Route path="/TestRoute/:slug" >
     <FetchRandomUser2 />
</Route>
```

So basically what i'm trying to do is get that slug in the first component and add it to end of the `url` in my `api` call, but i don't know how to do it, so is there a way to get that slug `param` and adding to end of that `api` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `:slug` parameter of your URL by accessing the `match` prop that ReactRouter gives you.

```
<Route 
    path="/TestRoute/:slug" 
    component={FetchRandomUser2}
/>
```

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Api extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const options = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('api_key'),
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        axios.get(`urlLink/${this.props.match.params.slug}` , options)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
            hi
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your FetchRandomUser2 component IS your Api component and you just aliased it on the import, you wanna pass it to a Route like so:

`<Route path="/TestRoute/:slug" component={FetchRandomUser2} />`

This means that when it is rendered, it will receive all of the relevant routing props such as match, location and history.

This means that inside of your Api component, you can get the slug by this doing something like `this.props.match.params.slug` and then using that in your request like `urlLink/${this.props.match.params.slug}`